# перемменные :"SYS_B_0" в Oracle

Tags: oracle11g

На сервере Oracle 11G установлен был параметер CURSOR_SHARING = FORCE
поменяли его на EXACT.
Проверил что точно выставлен EXACT
show paremeter cursor_sharing

NAME TYPE VALUE

---

cursor_sharing string EXACT

Спустя сутки смотрю на планы запросов и там полно переменных типа :"SYS_B_0".
Получается что cursor_sharing не отключился.

Почистил вручную кеш для одного запроса
exec DBMS_SHARED_POOL.PURGE ('0700011DBF132158, 1237695408', 'C');

Строю новый план этого запроса а там по прежнему переменные :"SYS_B_0".

Почему так?

Answer (score 0):

Дело было в том что EXACT срабатывает только для новых сессий. Если приложение держит сессию для него планы не меняются.